# Where to start exploring from in Fallout New Vegas: Old World Blues?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I've attached it in the game launcher, but do not know where to start from. No radio signal or something like that? Where do I look?

**Update:** According to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhWhEN6oPts)…

… it's at Mojave Drive-In, but I didn't get the signal. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install the latest patch. After I restarted the game I immediately got the signal :)